# Changing Path windows for nmap

Tags: python, windows, nmap

Code:

```
import nmap    
nscan = nmap.PortScanner()
```

> Error: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : C:\Python27'

I changed the path in the environmental variables and my program is still unable to find it. Any suggestions?

- Language Python
- OS Windows 7

Comment: Do you have [Nmap port scanner](https://nmap.org/) installed? The `python-nmap` package does not include it.

Comment: No I downloaded just the python files. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

'import nmap' means you're trying to import the 'python-nmap' module, which then calls the local nmap install. https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

You could install 'python-nmap' via PIP.

[image]

You would need to use 'subprocess' or another method to call nmap directly: [Python communicate() with NMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965188/python-communicate-with-nmap)